# Mouse click for webbrowser in java?

Tags: java, mouseevent, jwebbrowser

How can i get the link of website or video (example : in youtube) when i click one link in web browser and save to string a ; Have we other way to make the same thing?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is really general question. I can only say you should check

http://jsoup.org/
(great html parser)

http://www.seleniumhq.org/
(can be used as web **scraper** /spider)

Or in general, just google web crawling/scraping you can find enough resources.